# Comparing two ISO datetime strings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, date, time

I have a table where there are only DateTime stored as varchar's in ISO Format. I wanted to know what would be the MySQL query to compare given any random DateTime in iso format with the DateTime(in varchar) stored in the table.

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: datetime is stored as a varchar

Comment: can you show example data?

Comment: "2020-02-10T11:32:35.409+00:00" this is one of the datetime varchar from the column called as 'traceTime'.
Let's say I want to know how many rows exist in the table such that their 'traceTime' are less than 2020-02-21T08:40:07.749060

Comment: Do yourself a favor, use proper date/time data types from now on! https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  STR_TO_DATE('2020-01-03 17:35:48', GET_FORMAT(DATETIME,'ISO')) <
  STR_TO_DATE('2020-02-01 00:00:00', GET_FORMAT(DATETIME,'ISO'));
```

`GET_FORMAT(DATETIME,'ISO')` being similar to: `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s`, you can also do:

```
SELECT
  STR_TO_DATE('2020-01-03 17:35:48', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') <
  STR_TO_DATE('2020-02-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Once you have a `DateTime`, you can compare them using all operators: `=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `!=`, `BETWEEN`,...

Note: Avoid to store date/time in a `VARCHAR` column, because:

- You won't be able to take advantage of indexes, `STR_TO_DATE(mydate)` will have to be performed on every rows of your table and will cause a full table scan. The index will contain `mydate`, but not the result of `STR_TO_DATE(mydate)`, which means it will not be used.
- This will:

  - increase the complexity of all of your queries.
  - increase the amount of space used by your tables.
  - hurt the general performance of your database.

Another alternative is to avoid the transformation into date and benefit from the fact that ISO format can be sorted using ASCII comparison. In your specific case, you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE traceTime < '2020-02-21T08:40:07.749060'
```

But still, would be better if *traceTime* was of type `DATETIME`, the query would just be the same.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql   You can easly convert a string in a datetime  using

```
 str_to_date(your_string, your_format)

 str_to_date('31-12-2019', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format